# Delete first block of content in file with bash script

Tags: bash

I have a file that has eg 200 lines of code. the first paragraph that begins with `<?php` and ends with `?>` should be deleted with the `<?php` and `?>` tags. Here is an example for the file:

```
<?php
    some random code that should be removed
    ....
    ....
    ....

?><?php /*The beginning of the new <?php Tag is important and have to stay in the file!*/
  important code
   ....
   ....
   ....
   ....
?>
```

Is there a way to remove the first block of `<?php ?>` in the file with bash? If I would work with tail I only get the last part of the file and since the number of lines of code is different every time it would not be good to use it..

Answer (score 0):

`cat` it through this pipeline:

```
sed 's/^\(?>\)/\1\n/' | sed '1,/^?>$/d'
```

The 1st sed breaks the single-line `?><?php /*The beginning...` into two lines. That is convenient for the 2nd sed, which simply deletes the initial block of code. Both regexps are focused on the `?>` end-of-block marker.

If you prefer to avoid sed, the 2nd sed might be replaced with `perl -ne 'print unless 1../^\?>$/'`

Comment: [No need for `cat`](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html): the first `sed` can read the file.

Comment: Indeed. But `sed BLAHBLAH < some-filename-not-mentioned-by-OP | sed MOREBLAH` tends to muddy the waters of the discussion. I *would* be interested in solutions that rely on just a single `sed` or, much easier to implement, a single `perl` process. Then it becomes a matter of "is this clear enough that it easily convinces the reader it is correct?" A pair of generators in a single python process would be straightforward, but alas not a bash one-liner.

Comment: You can always put the redirection first to preserve the order: `<file sed blah | sed blahblah`.

Comment: It doesn't so much matter with `sed`, but in other cases such as `sort`, `wc -c` or `tac` (where random access, the ability to `seek()` and `tell()`, or the ability to reread content is algorithmically useful), reading a pipeline from `cat` can be much less efficient than reading from a real file descriptor. Encouraging folks to use `cat` is thus a bit of a smell: Even in the cases where the cost is trivial, forming a habit through common repetition means a practice is likely to be used even when that cost *isn't* so trivial.

Comment: The `cat` remark wasn't so much about what we could technically achieve, as about "what instructions would Fabian likely be able to usefully respond to?" Lots of folks understand that they can `cat` a file through a grep / sort / awk pipeline. I'll throw the "single process" challenge out there again. Certainly we can compute the desired result without a pipeline. But, do you care to offer a clear concise one-liner that computes the desired result? One that, upon casually reading it, is *obviously* correct? (Within the "bash" constraint: Put another way, I felt two processes was one too many.)

Comment: So I tried using it with `< functions.php | sed 's/^\(?>\)/\1\n/' | sed '1,/^?>$/d' > functions_new.php` but this only generates an empty `functions_new.php` file

Comment: I predicted the lack of clarity would lead to user errors. Davis Herring asked you to use '<' without '|'. Please use `cat`, or phrase it as Herring suggested: `< functions.php  sed 's/^\(?>\)/\1\n/' | sed '1,/^?>$/d' > functions_new.php`. That's one less '|' than you used.

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU awk:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{ORS=RS="?>"} NR>1{print}' file
<?php /*The beginning of the new <?php Tag is important and have to stay in the file!*/
  important code
   ....
   ....
   ....
   ....
?>
```

Explained:

```
BEGIN { ORS=RS="?>" } # set input and output record separators to php closing tag
NR>1 { print }        # output tag ending record starting from the second
```

This will fail if you have `?>` in constants and such. You could try to circumvents that with `ORS=RS="\n?>"`.

Comment: Using your awk statement only removes the beginning < from `<?php` and put it after the closing tag between the next `<?php` tag. So it then looks like this: `?>><?php`..

Comment: I guess you're not using GNU awk, then?